# onChange event not firing for input field with React

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

I am trying to render a simple input field, in which when the value is changed, a callback from the parent component will be called. My code is given below:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    myMethod() {
        alert("Test");
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Child cb={this.myMethod} />
        );
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <input type="text" placeholder="enter text" onChange="{this.props.cb}" />
        );
    }
}

Child.propTypes = {
    cb: React.PropTypes.func
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Parent />,
    document.getElementById("container")
);
```

My HTML code is:

```
<div id="container">

</div>
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Child: prop type `cb` is invalid; it must be a function, usually from React.PropTypes.
    in Child (created by Parent)
    in Parent

Warning: Failed form propType: Invalid prop `onChange` of type `string` supplied to `input`, expected `function`. Check the render method of `Child`.
```

I am new to React, and cannot really understand how else I should pass the callback to the Child component. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your onChange prop shouldn't be string:

```
class Child extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <input type="text" placeholder="enter text" onChange={this.props.cb} />
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Remove the quotation marks** around the value of `onChange`:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="enter text" onChange={this.props.cb} />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply!